# Total number of ways to select 4 out of 9 letters from the word HAPPINESS such that there are no P's and either 1 or 2 S's.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I divided it into two cases:

$$\text{case 1:}~~0 P, 1 S = {2 \choose 0}{2 \choose 1}{5 \choose 3} = 20$$
$$\text{case 2:}~~0 P, 2 S = {2 \choose 0}{2 \choose 2}{5 \choose 2} = 10$$

and then added those two up to get $30$ ways. Where did I go wrong? Also, is there a better way?

EDIT: I have a feeling that for case $1$, I should divide by $2$ or $2!$. Not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

$P's$ can be forgotten all together, primarily consider the $5$ letters $H,A,I,N,E$  along with $2\;S's$

Your answer of $30$ is correct if we assume (as is common) that **each letter is selected uniformly and independently at random**

And a simpler way to get the answer of $30$ would be to compute [*All selections*] - [*Selections w/o any S*]

= $\binom74 - \binom54 = 30$

This answer corresponds to treatment as a hypergeometric distribution with, say, one class having $5$ elements and the other having $2$ elements

The answer of $20$, on the other hand, is correct only if the $S's$ are to be treated as "add-ons"

Comment: Thank you! Can you please elaborate on your last sentence?

Comment: You consider ways to choose $3$ non-$S$ and just add an $S$ , or choose $2$ non-$S$ and add two $S's$, so $\binom53 +\binom52 = 20$, but I consider this to be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to multiply by $2$ in Case 1 because whichever $S$ you choose to use would result in the same selection, and you want to avoid double-counting.

So for case 1, $\binom53$, and for case 2, $\binom52$, so the total is $20$

Comment: So to avoid double counting in Case 1, I should have done: ${2 \choose 0} ({2 \choose 1} \div 2!) {5 \choose 3}$ ?

Comment: yes that's the same as $\binom53$

Comment: Please read true blue anil's answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I was assuming that all selections should be distinct, which is what I understood the question to mean.